# Are Quasi-Polynomial Time Functions Regularly Varying?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, slowly-varying-functions

Is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{(\ln ax)^k}}{e^{(\ln x)^k}}$$ finite for all positive real $a$ and $k$?

I have tried this on Desmos with $a$ and $k$ less than 2 where it seems to converge after around $10^{13}$, but with larger values the function is essentially a vertical line, though I'm not sure if it eventually converges.

This would answer if $e^{(\ln x)^k}$ (a quasi-polynomial time function) is regularly varying. Here is the Wikipedia definition of regularly varying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you define convergence, and I'm not familiar with SVF, but I tried the expression for small $k$. For $k=1 
 \ e^{\log a x - \log x} = a$ is a constant, but for $k=2$ 
$$
e^{\log^2(ax) - \log ^2 x} = e^{\log a \times \log ax^2} = a^{\log a} \times a^{2 \log x}
$$
which converges for $0<a \leq 1$ and diverges for $a>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know perhaps the upper bound for k for it to be SVF? In other words, upper bound for the above function above to converge (or lower bound for it to diverge)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The second expression converges for $0<a \leq 1$, diverges for $a>1$ and is not well-defined for negative values.

Comment: That answers my question, but how do you prove it diverges for a>1?

Comment: If $a>1, \ a^{\log x } = e^{\log a \log x} = e^{c \log x} = x^c \to \infty$ for $c>0$ (since $\log a >0$ for $a >1$

Comment: sorry I think I made a mistake. I was wondering about the bounds for k given any a>1, not a. Thanks!